# How to put ScrollView and OnTouchListener together in Android?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

There is ScrollView on layout, that has TextView inside, for scrolling text if one more then field heigth. But when i implements onTouchListener for ScrollView, default scroll of text doesn't work. How can i scroll text and handle touchEvent? For example: swipe left and right - turn to next quote, swipe up and down - scroll invisible text

[image]

Comment: why don't you use q ViewPager to swipe left n right ?

Comment: @Budius yes, i thougth about this component, but in my case View Pager would be hard for realization. After swipe i just get next cursor from database, so i needn't some fragments

Comment: You don't need to use fragments with ViewPager. Just saying.